# Facebook API PHP or Android

Tags: php, android, facebook

Is there a way to like a profile picture from Facebook SDK OR API (PHP or Android).

I want an user who logs in to see list of other people on Facebook, and be able to like their photo from within the app.

EDIT:

I have looked at the Facebook Graph API, but I had no prior experience. I am not asking you to give me code, I am asking you a simple question - can it be done? Because I have not seen any way of liking profile pictures from php or Android.

Comment: The question is way too broad, and does not show that you made reasonable research efforts before asking.

Comment: A profile picture is basically just a `Photo` object in API terms. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/likes/

Comment: Yes, but logically updating of Likes value is disabled.  And that is the main problem. They obviously disabled it because of the possibility for misuse.

Comment: You don’t want to update, you want to _create_ a like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A profile picture is basically just a `Photo` object in API terms, and as such can be liked as described here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/likes#Creating